# Android free/available space always returning 0 bytes

Tags: android

I am using context.getFilesDir() in case i cannot store a file in external storage. Then i use getAvailableBytes() or bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks(); based on build to check for free space.

On emulator and my test device, it works fine. But when others install my app from play they always get 0 byte as free space. Can someone give a hint or solution why this might be happening.

Shall I use Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() instead of context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), can this be the cause?. But then how it works in emulator or my dev device?

Please find the code below:

```
public static String getOutputDirectory(Context context)
{
    String outputstore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    if(outputstore == null)
    {
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
            outputstore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        else
            outputstore = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return outputstore;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public static boolean isFreeSpace(Context context)
{
    long bytesAvailable =0;
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(getOutputDirectory(context));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) 
    {
        bytesAvailable = stat.getAvailableBytes();
    }
    else
    {
        bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
    }

    long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024L * 1024L);
    if(megAvailable <= Constants.SPACE_CHECK_MEGABYTES)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if it serves the purpose, however it uses some deprecated methods.

```
public static long getAvailableStorage() {

        String storageDirectory = null;
        storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        try {
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(storageDirectory);
            long avaliableSize = ((long) stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat
                    .getBlockSize());
            return avaliableSize;
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But if external storage is not mounted then I need to write to internal storage. And I had tried the deprecated methods earlier, those also didn't worked.

Comment: Above described method is good for internal storage too, just check whether storage is mounted or not. I am having Xiaomi MI3 and it works on it very well as Xiaomi MI3 has only internal storage

Comment: But if not mounted then we will need to use context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() , isn't ? And this is different than Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: I believe no need of seperate API call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with String outputstore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"); In samsung and some other devices, this statement returns value instead of null, although there is no sd card mounted. Below code will fix it.

```
    String outputstore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    if(outputstore != null)
    {
        File secondaryStorage = new File(outputstore + File.separator + Constants.VIDEO_PREFIX);
        if(!(secondaryStorage.exists() && secondaryStorage.canWrite()))
        {
            //If sd card found(or a false positive) and not writable or exists
            //then try getting internal storages
            if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
                outputstore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            else
                outputstore = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
            outputstore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        else
            outputstore = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    }
```